# JQuery UI slider handle disappears because of conflict with megamenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I made a simple JQuery Slider on page that also has a jquery menu. My page look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/jquery.megamenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  

        <ul class="megamenu">
            <li><a href="/a/1">firstly</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b/2">secondly</a></li>
        </ul>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
              range: "min",
              value: 24,
              min: 24,
              max: 150,
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
              }
            });
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
          });
        </script>
        <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I included jquery twice above. If I don't reinclude it, I can't see the slider's handle.

If I do include it twice, I can see the slider, but the megamenu disappears. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); before the jquery code

**Also you need to put your div above script...**

```
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>

     <script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
              $j(function() {
                $j( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
                  range: "min",
                  value: 24,
                  min: 24,
                  max: 150,
                  slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $j( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
                  }
                });
                $j( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $j( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
              });
            </script>
```

Comment: also put all your jquery links at the top

Comment: Put jqeury no conflict script at the very top of html - before other scripts

Comment: adding no conflict doesn't bring the megamenu back, it just makes the slider disappear as well.

Comment: or modify another script if any before slider..I've done all on my app I am working on, as I am using lot's of plugins...just in case..you get used to it:)

Comment: thanks for your help. It doesn't work yet but I am on the right track.